# Screen scraping specific issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape GPS details for specific places, however my code, from some reason scrapes latitude only, despite longitude is available next to it. Any clue on putting it together will be much appreciated.

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re


tickers=['wies_Blizyn']
stats = {}

for ticker in tickers:
    page = requests.get('https://www.polskawliczbach.pl/' + ticker)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

    dic = {"name": [], "value": []}
    lis = soup.find_all("ul", class_="list-group")
    for li in lis:
        a = li.find_all("li")[0:1]
        for b in a:
            error = 0
            try:
                print(b.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip(), "\t",
                      b.find("span").text.replace(" ", "").replace(",", ""))
                dic["name"].append(b.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip())
                dic["value"].append(b.find("span").text.replace(" ", ","))
            except Exception as e:
                pass

    df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

Comment: Can you share expected output so it will be easy to understand!

Comment: Hi, sure. There you go...

Comment: Współrzędne GPS   20.761111, 51.108056

Comment: Use `find_all` to get all spans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web page tab of Identyfikatory given it will be easy to identify data for that i have used css selector

```
tickers=['wies_Blizyn']
stats = {}
main_dict={"name": [], "value": []}

for ticker in tickers:
    page = requests.get('https://www.polskawliczbach.pl/' + ticker)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
    
    main_data=soup.select("div.panel-body > ul.list-group >li")[0]
    main_dict['value']=[[i.get_text() for i in main_data.find_all("span")]]
    main_dict['name']=main_data.find(text=True,recursive=False)
    
df=pd.DataFrame(main_dict)
```

Output:

```
name             value
0   Współrzędne GPS [20.761111, 51.108056]
```

Comment: Works like a charm. This is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks for your quick help.Much, much appreciated.